# Status bar not animating in iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I'm working on an iPhone app with XCode 10 and iOS 11.

I'm trying to have the status bar animate out of the screen when moving from one scene to another.

In my first view controller (TableViewController) I declare:

```
var isStatusBarHidden = false
```

I then add the following:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return isStatusBarHidden
}

override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return .slide
}
```

and then in the prepare method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "resultSegue" {
        ...

        isStatusBarHidden = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        })
    }
}
```

In the second view controller (ViewController) I have

```
var isStatusBarHidden = true
```

and

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

The animation works fine on the iPhone 8. However, on the iPhone X, even though the status bar does appear and disappear, it doesn't animate.

How can I have the animation happen on iPhone X too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your code to work nicely, as long as I did not have the first view controller embedded in an UINavigationController.

If you have your first view controller in an UINavigationController:
Make a subclass, f.ex CustomNavigationController:

```swift
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    var isStatusBarHidden: Bool = false

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return isStatusBarHidden
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return .slide
    }

}
```

Then in the prepare for segue method in the first view controller:

```
if let navigationController = navigationController as? CustomNavigationController {
    navigationController.isStatusBarHidden = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    })
}
```

And as you have in your second view controller:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Then it animated nicely for me on the iPhone X.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to make it work. Should I place the subclass code at the bottom of the first view controller?

Comment: Do you use a navigation controller? The subclass code is a new class inheriting from UINavigationController. If you use a UINavigationController, make sure you set it as a CustomNavigationController (In storyboard, or code. Depends on how the app is built). If you still have problems then more info about how you have done things could be useful. Additionally, what kind of segue do you use to present the second view controller?

Comment: Finally got it to work! I set the UINavigationController to the custom class in storyboard. That's what I had missing. Thanks for the help!